# Cisco Firewall 5512 NAT cause IP randomly mapping to the host

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-ios

I have an ASA 5512 firewall that has configured with 2 public IP addresses.
I use static nat to explosive https service and use PAT to allow my DMZ web server to access the Internet. The CLI are shown below:

```
PAT:
object network pat-pub-ip
    host 49.xx.xx.2

object network my_dmz_web
     nat (inside,outside) dynamic pat-pub-ip interface


static NAT:
object network nat-pub-range
   range 49.xx.xx.0 49.xx.xx.1

object network web-https
    host 10.128.10.10
    nat (inside,outside) static nat-pub-range service tcp https https

ACL:
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any
access-list 101 extended permit ip any any
access-group 101 in interface inside
```

I still have other hosts like: 10.128.10.20, 10.128.10.30, 10.128.10.40 .

The weird thing is when I use public IP e.g. 49.xx.xx.0 and 49.xx.xx.1, they can directly access the hosts 10.128.10.20 and 10.128.10.30 accordingly, but there is no any NAT except what I listed above.

for example:
ssh 49.xx.xx.0, this is directly connect to the the 10.128.10.20, just like ssh 10.128.10.20.

I've tried reset ASA and reconfig again, same result, is anyone has been face the same situation before? thanks

Comment: Are the `49.x.x.x` addresses the addresses you use on your own network? If so, any addresses in your network do not need NAT. Remember that IP knows no difference between public and private addresses.

Comment: No, I just use them as NAT IP addresses through internal physical interface gi0/0. like:
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description To-Internet
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.13.1.18 255.255.255.0

Comment: Then how do you use them as a source address? What device has that address in order to connect to your internal hosts? I think you need to explain further what you are actually doing that you think is incorrect.

Comment: These public IP addresses were given by IDC, I use NAT to connect within my local network.